# Text editor that shows preview window of CSS classes, ID's and elements

Tags: notepad++, text-editors, sublime-text-2, css, dreamweaver

I use a combination of Notepad++, Sublime and also Dreamweaver. I still use DW because of its really handy CSS Styles window, and for me its the quickest way of navigating through large CSS files.

I'd love to purely use one of the other two, and Sublime comes closest with its miniview, but what I really want is a list of all my CSS elements so I can quickly jump to them easily. What I would also love is for CSS comments to be shown visually in the preview window as this would further make navigating the file much easier!

Surely I'm not the only one to find frustrations with editing large CSS files. It really is an unorganized science!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try SynWrite editor. It shows CSS as tree view:
[image]